# rendering partial with js.haml in AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, partial-views

I'm having troubles with rendering response via AJAX.

Here is how my .js.haml view looks like:

```
:plain
  $("#cart").replaceWith("#{escape_javascript(render 'carts/cart')}");
```

HTML code in partial is rendered incorrectly and breaks HTML layout. In web inspector of Safari, I'm getting following XHR response:

> $("#cart").replaceWith("      Your orderh2>

I is clear, that HTML code is broken: h2 tag is not closed properly, attribute values are not enclosed in brackets etc.

A part of page, that was replaced with such a response will be broken.

I've also tried some other techniques, like this:

```
!= "$('#cart').replaceWith('#{escape_javascript(render 'carts/cart')}');"
```

The result is the same.

However, simple cases, like

```
:plain
  $("#cart").replaceWith("<p>Test</p>");
```

Are working fine.

The problem is in rendering of the partial.

PS: This partial is 100% correct, because it is used by regular page rendering.

What can be wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of R3 you on? I know the later ones requires a `raw` with that `escape_javascript`. Think that kicks in on 3.0.8. But, that might be one place to look.

Comment: Yes, I'm on Rails 3.0.8. What is raw ? Give an example, please.

Comment: `raw(escape_javascript(...your render...))` Hopefully this can get you going.

Comment: I've found the reason. It is a bug in Rails 3.0.8. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1553

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason. escape_javascript function work incorrectly, because of a [bug](http://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1553), found in Rails 3.0.8.